# Azure B2C - Automation - EnableIEFKeySetGraphApis Feature

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to automate deployment of B2C TrustFramework policies and keysets.
For Custom policies, everything works as expected but I am having some problem listing keySets using the Graph API.

- I've created a local user with `B2C IEF Keyset administrator` and `B2C IEF Policy administrator` roles.
- I've created an app registration with these delegated permissions: `Policy.ReadWrite.TrustFramework`, `TrustFrameworkKeySet.Read.All`, `TrustFrameworkKeySet.ReadWrite.All`
- Calling the AAD Token endpoint, I am able to get an access_token with the desired scopes for the graph api resource.
- I am trying then to call the `List KeySets` endpoint using the access_token (as bearer token in the authorization hearder)

  ```
  GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/trustFramework/keySets HTTP/1.1
  Authorization: Bearer {{my access_token}}
  ```

And I am getting this response from the Graph API (`403 Forbidden`):

````
```
{
    "error": {
    "code": "AADB2C",
    "message": "Unauthorized. Access to this Api requires feature: 'EnableIEFKeySetGraphApis' for the tenant: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.",
    "innerError": {
        "correlationId": "4674e4c9-933e-4e70-a26b-ed59e40dc088",
        "date": "2019-06-04T08:55:32",
        "request-id": "d796beda-62be-46a8-afa2-cf53d29409b5"
        }
    }
}
```
````

This tenant was created before Custom Policies went GA (so not sure if it is related) but how do I activate the **EnableIEFKeySetGraphApis** feature ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a private Preview Sample available in GitHub for Graph API Key Sets.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ActiveDirectory-B2C-MSGraph-PolicyAndKeysets

try this and see you able to list your keysets or not.

Comment: Thanks ! I went through the doc but haven't read it carefully :-)